# JS convert delimiter separated string to array elements

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, logic, delimiter

Just for fun, I wrote a quick script to take in a string with comma separated characters, I use the commas to denote a different word, and I output an array with the words as elements. My issue is with my logic - this only works for commas in the original string.

What is happening is that the algorithm only looks at the first element (a comma) in the delimiter array that I provide when calling my function. I'm thinking about using a boolean as a flag somewhere, but not sure if this is really the best way to go about it. Any advice?

```js
var stringToArray = function(delimiterArray, originalString) {
  var arrayOutput = []
  var tempWord = ""
  for (var i = 0; i < originalString.length; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < delimiterArray.length; j++) {

      var currentCharacter = originalString.charAt(i)
      var currentDelimiter = delimiterArray[j]

      while (currentCharacter != currentDelimiter) {
        tempWord += currentCharacter
          //once we hit a delimiter, break so that we can move onto the next conditional statement. 
        break
      }

      if (currentCharacter === currentDelimiter) {
        //push word onto the array to hold each string, and then break out so we can go back to the iteration of the nested loops
        arrayOutput.push(tempWord)
        tempWord = ""
        break
      }

      //we break out of the second for loop -> 
      break
    }

  }
  return arrayOutput
}

delims = [',', '.', ';', ' ']
originalString = "USA,Canada,Mexico,Bermuda,Grenada,Belize"

finalOutput = stringToArray(delims, originalString)
console.log(finalOutput)
```

If I use a '.' as a delimiter in the string that I'm using as an argument, my algorithm fails. I implemented this in C using boolean flags (a long time ago) where I had to write way more code because I wasn't using any built in functions (had to find the length of everything so I could malloc enough memory for data structures to store stuff). Don't want to revisit that old code, though.

Comment: Javascript already has a `split()` function to do this. Also, if you want to search an array for something, you can use `indexOf()` instead of writing your own loop.

Comment: @Barmar Yep, fully aware. As stated in the first line, this was just for fun. I want to implement it myself.

Comment: Your `while()` loop never modifies `currentCharacter` or `currentDelimiter`, so it will loop forever.

Comment: But since it has a `break` to prevent looping, it's really just an `if()` statement. Why did you use `while`?

Comment: Why complicate things -> **https://jsfiddle.net/0hbmgbuy/**

Comment: @adeneo He said it's an intellectual exercise, he's trying to understand how this stuff works internally.

Comment: @adeneo [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems)

Comment: @George I've yet to dip into regex so I totally skipped over that solution after looking at for a second. Besides, it didn't actually answer my question at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding the current character to `tempWord` if it doesn't match the current delimiter. So if the current character doesn't match the first delimiter, it gets added to tempWord, even though it might match one of the other delimiters. You need to go through the entire delimiter array before you can determine if the character is a delimiter or not.

```js
var stringToArray = function(delimiterArray, originalString) {
  var arrayOutput = [];
  var tempWord = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < originalString.length; i++) {
    var currentCharacter = originalString.charAt(i)
    var isDelimiter = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < delimiterArray.length; j++) {

      var currentDelimiter = delimiterArray[j]

      if (currentCharacter == currentDelimiter) {
        isDelimiter = true;
        //once we hit a delimiter, break so that we can move onto the next conditional statement. 
        break;
      }

    }
    if (isDelimiter) {
      arrayOutput.push(tempWord);
      tempWord = "";
    } else {
      tempWord += currentCharacter;
    }

  }
  return arrayOutput;
}

delims = [',', '.', ';', ' ']
originalString = "USA,Canada.Mexico,Bermuda,Grenada,Belize"

finalOutput = stringToArray(delims, originalString)
console.log(finalOutput)
```

For some reason, this seems to be an incredibly common error by people writing their own array searching code.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now haha. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You had a couple of issues:

- You used a break in a while loop.  This did nothing, it breaks out of the while loop, not out of the upper loop.
- The break at the end of the for loop did nothing, it breaks out of the for loop.
- You were missing the last word, you need to push this onto the array at the end.
- I have broken out the deliminator check to the `isDeliminator()` function.  This makes the code clearer, more modular (you could use it again) and typically reduces the bugs.

Below is my code.

```js
function stringToArray(delimiterArray, originalString) {
      var arrayOutput = [];
      var tempWord = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < originalString.length; i++) {

          var currentCharacter = originalString.charAt(i);

          if (isDeliminator(currentCharacter)) {
              //push word onto the array to hold each string, and then break out so we can go back to the iteration of the nested loops
              arrayOutput.push(tempWord);
              tempWord = '';
          } else {
              tempWord += currentCharacter;
          }

      }

      // Push the last work onto the array
      arrayOutput.push(tempWord);

      return arrayOutput;
}

function isDeliminator(char) {
    for (var i = 0; i < delims.length; i += 1) {
        if (char === delims[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var delims = [',', '.', ';', ' '];
var inputString = 'USA.Canada,Mexico;Bermuda,Grenada,Belize';
var finalOutput = stringToArray(delims, inputString);
console.log(finalOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a corrected script, with the changes commented:

```js
var stringToArray = function(delimiterArray, originalString) {
  var arrayOutput = []
  var tempWord = ""
  for (var i = 0; i < originalString.length; i++) {
    // Set currentCharacter here, as it does not depend on j:
    var currentCharacter = originalString.charAt(i)

    for (var j = 0; j < delimiterArray.length; j++) {

      var currentDelimiter = delimiterArray[j]

      if (currentCharacter === currentDelimiter) {
        //push word onto the array to hold each string, and then break out so we can go back to the iteration of the nested loops
        arrayOutput.push(tempWord)
        tempWord = ""
        break
      }

      //No, we don't break out of the second for loop -> 
    }

    // Moved out of the j-loop, and turned into an IF without BREAK:
    if (currentCharacter != currentDelimiter) {
      tempWord += currentCharacter
    }

  }
  return arrayOutput
}

var delims = [',', '.', ';', ' ']
var originalString = "USA,Canada,Mexico,Bermuda,Grenada,Belize"

var finalOutput = stringToArray(delims, originalString)
document.write(JSON.stringify(finalOutput))
```